# Sequence of learning mathematics from basic algebra to calculus.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, self-learning, economics

What would be a step by step sequence of learning mathematics from basic algebra to basic calculus? I pose this question because I am in the process of self-learning mathematics as a preparation for a study of econometrics.

Any comments and suggestions appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not able to make sense out of your "basic algebra to basic calculus"...

Comment: By basic algebra I mean that one has just started to learn algebra and is trying to understand the terms like expression, term, factor, product, exponent, radical etc. The basic calculus is that one has gained enough skills in algebra to take the beginner's steps in calculus. I hope that I am being clear.

Comment: Being a freshman, I can say I really enjoyed getting there directly. But reading some books about calculus may help you, at least for me, the best way to learn math is actually doing it!

Answer (score 4):

The areas of mathematics to study to get from Pre-Algebra to Calculus is:

- Basic Math
- Pre-Algebra
- Algebra
- Algebra II
- Trigonometry
- Calculus

(Source for list, a flow chart a community college created to aid students in choosing math classes http://web.clark.edu/math/docs-students/Math_Flow_Chart.pdf)

To see individual concepts per area of math, use KahnAcademy. They have a page for each area of math with list of topics and sub-topics. For example, their [Algebra page](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/) lists out the basic concepts, and upon clicking them, will show you an in-depth list (of videos you can use to learn) of what you need to learn to master that concept.